# How to generate Shake Gesture using Swift (XCTest)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xctest

I am writing UI Tests using Swift and XCTest for my application, i have to shake the device to get the notifications, can you please tell me how i can generate the shake gesture within code.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is stupidly simple. All you need to do is to send *"com.apple.UIKit.SimulatorShake"* Darwin notification. See the example code below:

**SimulatorShaker.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SimulatorShaker : NSObject

+ (void)performShake;

@end
```

**SimulatorShaker.m**

```
#import "SimulatorShaker.h"
#import "notify.h"

@implementation SimulatorShaker

+ (void)performShake {
    notify_post("com.apple.UIKit.SimulatorShake");
}

@end
```

If you work with the Swift project you'll have to add a bridging header. Usually Xcode suggests creating the bridging header automatically when you add some Objective-C files to the project. See how to [set up the header manually](https://javedmultani16.medium.com/adding-a-swift-bridging-header-b6b0a7ab895f) in case you don't find the bridging header or experience any issues building a project

**Note:** the Darwin Notification API is private to 3rd party developers and Apple won't allow such code to be released to App Store. But you won't experience any bother if you use the SimulatorShaker for UI test purposes only.

Comment: There's a lot of other cool stuff you can do using Darwin notifications. You may see some of the known notification identifiers [here](https://iphonedev.wiki/index.php/Notifications) and [here](https://github.com/facebook/idb/issues/202)

Answer (score -1):

#### Swift 3

```
override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
    return true
}

override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if motion == .motionShake {
        print("Shaked")
    }
}
```

Comment: This is how to handle a shake gesture, not perform one

Answer (score -1):

There is still no support for shake gestures when using XCUITest. I would suggest you do a work around(two finger tap?) if you can OR use a tool like Appium which supports shake.

Answer (score -2):

Well first you should add the following method to your `UIViewController` subclass:

```
override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Next is to add the `motionEnded:withEvent:` method:

```
override func motionEnded(motion: UIEventSubtype, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if motion == .MotionShake {
      print("Shaked")
    }
}
```

Good luck :)

Comment: I didn't have to use the canBecomeFirstResponder() delegate in Swift 2.*

Comment: This doesn't answer how to generate the shake gesture from the code/test.